# Remove object from a nested object javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

I have an object:

```
s={
   "ex_obj":{
      "arr1":[
         {
            "id":"item1",
            "version":"2020-04-29t14:14:08"
         },
         {
            "id":"item1",
            "version":"2020-04-29t14:14:09"
         }
      ],
      "arr2":[
         {
            "id":"item1",
            "version":"2020-04-29t14:14:10"
         },
         {
            "id":"item1",
            "version":"2020-04-29t14:14:09"
         }
      ]
   }
}
```

I need to remove a nested object from the array of values of `ex_obj` such that the value of version meets a criteria  and store the key of that object it's key in an array.

For example, if I want the object without the child object with a **version** `"2020-04-29t14:14:09"` my output would be

```
{
   "ex_obj":{
      "arr1":[
         {
            "id":"item1",
            "version":"2020-04-29t14:14:08"
         }
      ],
      "arr2":[
         {
            "id":"item1",
            "version":"2020-04-29t14:14:10"
         }
      ]
   }
}
```

Along with an array `['arr1', 'arr2']` as I want the array of keys whose values have been changed.

Here is my attempt. I could remove the object but of course couldn't capture the key.

```
Object.values(s['ex_obj']).map(e =>e)
          .map(x =>
            x.filter((f) => {
              return f.version != "2020-04-29t14:14:09";
            }));
```

How can I go about getting the output?

Comment: Please show what you tried so we can help you fix it. We're not going to write it from scratch for you.

Comment: Use `Object.entries()` to loop over all the properties. Then use `.findIndex()` to find the index of the object that matches the version criteria, and `splice()` to remove it from the array.

Comment: And when `findIndex()` finds a match, you can push the key onto the array of keys that were updated.

Comment: @Barmar I've made edits

Answer (score 0):

`x` is a local variable containing a reference to the array. Assigning to it doesn't modify the property it came from.

Use `Object.entries()` so you get both the property name and value, then you can assign back to the property. This will also allow you to make the array of properties that were modified.

```js
s = {
  "ex_obj": {
    "arr1": [{
        "id": "item1",
        "version": "2020-04-29t14:14:08"
      },
      {
        "id": "item1",
        "version": "2020-04-29t14:14:09"
      }
    ],
    "arr2": [{
        "id": "item1",
        "version": "2020-04-29t14:14:10"
      },
      {
        "id": "item1",
        "version": "2020-04-29t14:14:09"
      }
    ]
  }
}

let updated = [];
let remove = "2020-04-29t14:14:09";
Object.entries(s.ex_obj).forEach(([key, array]) => {
  let filtered = array.filter(({
    version
  }) => version != remove);
  if (filtered.length < array.length) {
    s.ex_obj[key] = filtered;
    updated.push(key);
  }
});

console.log(s);
console.log(updated);
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are allowed to destroy the original object, you could just loop over the keys and then filter the arrays:

```js
let s={
   "ex_obj":{
      "arr1":[
         {
            "id":"item1",
            "version":"2020-04-29t14:14:08"
         },
         {
            "id":"item1",
            "version":"2020-04-29t14:14:09"
         }
      ],
      "arr2":[
         {
            "id":"item1",
            "version":"2020-04-29t14:14:10"
         },
         {
            "id":"item1",
            "version":"2020-04-29t14:14:09"
         }
      ]
   }
}

let ex_obj=s.ex_obj;
for(let key of Object.keys(ex_obj))
  ex_obj[key]=ex_obj[key].filter(item=>item.version!=="2020-04-29t14:14:09");
console.log(s);
```

If you have to make a copy, that's not very different either, just you have to use some kind of cloning, like the JSON-hack, or another:

```js
let s={
   "ex_obj":{
      "arr1":[
         {
            "id":"item1",
            "version":"2020-04-29t14:14:08"
         },
         {
            "id":"item1",
            "version":"2020-04-29t14:14:09"
         }
      ],
      "arr2":[
         {
            "id":"item1",
            "version":"2020-04-29t14:14:10"
         },
         {
            "id":"item1",
            "version":"2020-04-29t14:14:09"
         }
      ]
   }
}

let ex_obj=s.ex_obj;
let result={};
for(let key of Object.keys(ex_obj))
  result[key]=JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(ex_obj[key].filter(item=>item.version!=="2020-04-29t14:14:09")));
result={ex_obj:result};
console.log(result);
```